# how to get back to the terminal while busy

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I am running an install from the terminal but I need to get access to a file in the same directory.

What gets me back is bg or bz?  I know it is something like that.

Comment: can you explain little better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: Suspend to background
- `fg 1`: Resume first job on foreground
- `bg 1`: Resume first job on background
- `jobs`: Get a list of jobs

See [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) for a full reference of options.

Comment: I don't want to suspend it.  I did it earlier by putting the job running in the background but I now can't remember what it was.

Comment: I was able to pull off the crtl + z and fg since I did it extremely quick.  Last time it froze with that method but thanks.

Comment: you have to suspend it first to be able to send it to the background. I don't think there is another option once the job is already running?